# How to get component name with react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an state defined as:

```
 const [page, setPage] = useState<React.ReactNode>(<UserChats />);
```

How can i get current state's component name? I tried `page.type.name`, but it says that

> Property 'type' does not exist on type 'string | number | boolean |
> ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor> | ReactFragment
> | ReactPortal'.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: This feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I have a nav bar, when i'm in X page, i want the icon to be white. Since i'm changing which component is being rendered i wanna know it's name. Like Component X ? color Y : color Z

Comment: Have you looked at `react-router` because it seems like you are wanting to make a router

Comment: That should be a prop in your router. So the component itself would analyze the route and change its colors based on whether itself is the 'active' route.

Comment: Yes, i was working with react-router. But what i`m doing is rendering two components at the same time. So in this case the react router would be impossible to use right? Because i just want to change one component without changing the whole page.

Comment: You can easily do that using the Outlet component https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/outlet